sed to put a dash - between alphabet group and numbers group in .txt file
I have a txt file containing lines of text with the pattern alphabets then numbers in one string, where there could be any number of letters in front and any numbers after.
ABC123 
ACDEG12 
AR123456 
C001

I want to put a dash between the alphabet group and the numbers group. The desired output in the same file is the following.
ABC-123
ACDEG-12 
AR-123456 
C-001

I tried sed -i '' 's/\([^0-9-]\)\([0-9]\+\)/$1-$2/' file.txt, but it doesn't work.
What am I missing? I am on a Mac.

doesn't work = "no change at all" or = "here is my failed output" ? Please update your question with your current sample ouput. (you code looks workable (without actually testing it)). IF your data was created or passed thru an MS Windows machine, the preclean the file with dos2unix file.txt. Good luck.

what do you think \+ and $1 do? check -E

I think you may be confusing  substitution in perl with substitution in sed.

If those are the only lines, simply s/[0-9]/-&/ --> will insert - before the first numeral.

So just in case there are only letter and only number options, I created this file (I too am on a Mac):
echo -e "ABC123\nACDEG12\nAR123456\nC001\nABC\n123" > file.txt

There are 3 issues with your original sed command:

You're missing a quantifier on the letters portion: \([^0-9-]\)
+ nor \+ work by default on Mac sed since by default it uses basic regular expressions.
Replacements should be \1 and \2, not $1 and $2

The most portable way to do this is using {1,} for one or more, which needs to be escaped like \{1,\}:
❯ sed -i '' 's/^\([^0-9-]\{1,\}\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/\1-\2/' file.txt
❯ cat file.txt
ABC-123
ACDEG-12
AR-123456
C-001
ABC
123

If you want a simpler-looking expression, you can use -E to use extended (modern) regular expressions. If you're only planning on using this on your Mac that should be fine. If you plan to use this in other linux flavors, containers, etc., I would test this there first to make sure it works as expected - it's not as portable as the first option:
❯ sed -i '' -E 's/^([^0-9-]+)([0-9]+)$/\1-\2/' file.txt
❯ cat file.txt
ABC-123
ACDEG-12
AR-123456
C-001
ABC
123

